# Javascript on submit event multiple fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, click

When this function run for the 1st time, it's ok, but if I run this function for the second time, it runs automatically 2 times, if I run this function for the 3rd time, it runs automatically 3 times.
I'm not using iterative cycle.
How can i solve this problem?

```
$("#form_personal").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var $id_last_messaggistica = $('div[id^="messaggistica"]:last');
    var num = parseInt( $id_last_messaggistica.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
    document.getElementById('idlastmessaggistica').value = num;
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission
    $.post( post_url, form_data, function( response ) {
        $("#server-results").html( response );
    });
    event.stopPropagation? event.stopPropagation() : event.cancelBubble = true;
});
```

This is the code with the click call

```
$("#btn_personalinfo").click(function(event){
        $("#form_personal").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
            var $id_last_messaggistica = $('div[id^="messaggistica"]:last');
            var num = parseInt( $id_last_messaggistica.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
            document.getElementById('idlastmessaggistica').value = num;
            var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
            var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission
            $.post( post_url, form_data, function( response ) {
              $("#server-results").html( response );
            });
        });
    });
```

this is the submit button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6" id="btn_personalinfo">Salva</button>
```

This is the tag form

```
<form name="personal_info" id="form_personal" method="post" action="Curriculum/updateInformazioniPersonali">
```

Comment: How many times are you adding the submit event and function to your form?

Comment: Looks like multiple times registering the submit function, is the `$("#form_personal").submit(function(event){` called after the submit is done (e.g. page reloaded)?

Comment: You can remove `event.stopPropagation? event.stopPropagation() : event.cancelBubble = true;` they are already handled by the `event.preventDefault();` - you have another problem than the code shown - likely an event handler added inside a mouseover or a click

Comment: Possible your "response" data may contain submit event again so the number of time you call it regenerate on all call.

Comment: could you post html content ??

Comment: @maulik my "response" data doesn't containt submit event again.

Comment: @mplungjan i removed `event.stopPropagation? event.stopPropagation() : event.cancelBubble = true;`, problem persist. I edited the post with more informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do NOT want to add a submit event handler to the form when clicking the button. It will likely result in a mess of submissions

The code you want is this and nothing else - assuming `idlastmessaggistica` is a UNIQUE ID

```js
$("#form_personal").on("submit",function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
  var $id_last_messaggistica = $('div[id^="messaggistica"]:last');
  var num = parseInt($id_last_messaggistica.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1;
  $('#idlastmessaggistica').val(num);
  var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
  var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission
  $.post(post_url, form_data, function(response) {
    $("#server-results").html(response);
  });
});
```